# View jar file content sorted by name

Tags: linux, bash, jar, centos

I am on a CentOS environment and tools are limited to command line.

I am trying to list the content of a jar file by name so I can compare it to a local source.

Is there a way to List the content of a jar file `jar tvf` and pipe this to something where I can have the content sorted alphabetically by name?

Answer (score 0):

After some quick reading about sort, I realized I just have to pipe it to sort. No wonder I can't find an answer here, too simple.